# How to build a self-contained library using webpack so that it can be imported/required?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I wrote a library that does something (duh). My client needs to run the code on AWS as serverless function, but my library uses ES6 featured that are not supported on the old version of Node.js that AWS is running.

So I want to build my code so that it will just export the function that does what we need and can be `require`d in other scripts. Webpack builds all right, and the code runs as it's supposed to, but nothing is exported from the packed code.

Here's the MCVE:

### `webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require('path');
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
module.exports = {
    entry: ['babel-polyfill', './serverless_function.js'],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('dist'),
        filename: 'serverless_lib.js',
        library: 'ServerlessTest',
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
            { test: /\.jsx$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ }
        ]
    },
    target: 'node',
    externals: [nodeExternals()]
}
```

### `serverless_function.js`

This one is supposed to be packed. It includes and uses the code from my library to do the task that should be done on AWS. In this example, it just reads a file and returns it.

The result should be packed and put into `dist/serverless_library.js`, as written in `webpack.config.js`.

```
require("babel-core/register");
const fs = require("fs");

function ReadTestFile() {
    return new Promise(function (res, rej) {
        fs.readFile("test.txt", function (err, data) {
            if (err)
                rej(err);
            else
                res(data);
        })
    });
}

async function testFunction(event, context, callback) {
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {

            "Content-Type": "text/plain",
            "Content-Disposition": "inline; filename=\"test.txt\""
        },
        body: await ReadTestFile()
    };
    return callback(null, response);
}
console.log("Exporting function: ", testFunction);
export default testFunction;
```

### `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": [ "es2015", "stage-0" ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "transform-runtime",
      {
        "polyfill": false,
        "regenerator": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

### `server.js`

This is a test script which should be able to load the **packed** library and use it.

```
'use strict';
var http = require('http');
var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;

const SERVERLESS = require("./dist/serverless_lib");
// The serverless should be a function, since that's what I export in serverless_function.js
if (typeof SERVERLESS != "function") {
    throw new Error("Webpack still didn't pack the export correctly!");
}

http.createServer(async function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.rawHeaders);

    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });

    SERVERLESS(null, null, (unused, response) => {
        res.end(new Buffer(response.body));
    });
}).listen(port);
```

I created a github repo that contains everything together: https://github.com/Darker/webpack-library-example

I hope this example is sufficient.

Comment: Do you actually want to use Webpack? If you're just compiling to run the code on Node anyway, there's nothing gained by bundling up all your code into one file.

Comment: It makes deployment simpler since you only need to transfer one file that only exports one function.

Comment: Fair enough, I just wanted to verify since it affects what possible answers might be.

Comment: I guess you build with the `-p` flag so webpack defaults to using uglify. Since your entry point doesn't call any code the entire bundle is considered dead code and removed by uglify. You could try to build without `-p` and see what the results are. I think the consumer of your module should just npm install it and use their own bundler, that way their bundler can remove any code they don't use. You could also add `if(Date.now()===0){callSomeFunction();}` and see that now `callSomeFunction` cannot be removed because uglify cannot be sure it is never called.